# Prove the inequality regarding complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $\theta_i\in [0,\pi/6],i=1,2,3,4,5$.And $$\sin \theta_1\ z^4 + \sin\theta_2 \ z^3 + \sin\theta_3 \ z^2 + \sin\theta_4 \ z + \sin\theta_5=2$$ Prove that  $|z|\gt \frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|\le\dfrac34$

and as $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi6,0\le\sin y\le\dfrac12$

$$|\sum_{i=0}^4\sin\theta_i z^{4-i}|\le\sum_{i=0}^4|\sin\theta_i z^{4-i}|$$

$\le$max$(\sin\theta_i)\sum_{i=0}^4\left(\dfrac34\right)^i<\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{1-(3/4)^{4+1}}{1-\dfrac34}<\dfrac1{2(1-3/4)}$

Comment: Will you please elaborate your explanation.

Comment: @Ayushakj See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Comment: $(\sin\theta_i)\sum_{i=0}^5\left(\dfrac34\right)^i<\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{1-(3/4)^6}{1-\dfrac34}<\dfrac1{2(q-3/4)}$,in this how to take value of z

Comment: @Ayushakj,This is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction. I've chosen $|z|\le\dfrac34$

Comment: The highest power of $z$ in the expression from the question is $z^4$, not $z^5$. Also $q$ seems to be undefined.

Comment: @MartinR, Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

$\theta_i\in [0,\pi/6]$ implies that $0 \le \sin \theta_i \le \frac 12$.
So it follows from your equation that 
$$
 2 \le \frac 12 \left( 1 + |z| + |z|^2 + |z|^3 + |z|^4 \right)
$$
or, with $r = |z|$,
$$
f(r) = 1+ r+r^2 +r^3 +r^4 - 4 \ge 0
$$
$f(r)$ is monotonically increasing in $r$ and $f(3/4) < 0$,
therefore a solution must satisfy $r > 3/4$.

A numerical computation with PARI/GP

```
? solve(r=0, 1, 1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4-4)
%1 = 0.88817966758531001825082741056489343552
```

shows that $r > 0.888$.